# Symantec Exec Backup 2010 R3 bugs out with not enough space when it clearly can reuse overwritable items

Tags: backupexec

I'm having some problems with my backup. It's acting strange. Even that I have a lot of over writable items in Media Sets and manages to backup some stuff it fails for other.

> Backup- D:Storage device "Backup-to-Disk Folder 0001" reported an
>   error on a request to write data to media. Error reported: Not enough space. V-79-57344-34034 - An attempt to write data past the
>   end of the media has failed. Verify- D: RAID 10An inconsistency was
>   encountered on the storage media in Backup-to-Disk Folder 0001.
>   V-79-57344-33994 - The data being read from the media is inconsistent.

Clearly I don't have space on that drive but that is only because Symantec fills it up till it's full. But then it has lots of `reusable overwritable` items that it should be able to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question but may be an alternate solution for you. I've never had any luck getting BE to overwrite B2D file so I run a batch file that deletes them after they've been backed up to tape. If I need to restore data from the B2D files I restore them first, then the data from them.